# Removing columns where all values are NaT on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have a dataframe what collects data from an Excel sheet. The problem is, sometimes there are a lot of empty data in the columns, like you can see here in this picture:
[image]

My question is: how can i remove those the columns where all values are `NaT`? I know that using `my_df = my_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` won't work and I can't change the data directly on the spreadsheet.

Comment: "df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')" should work. Do you get an error?

Comment: There is no errors at all, but nothing happens to the dataframe.

Comment: Well without access of your data... Hard to tell. Could you copy at least a part or the entre dataframe in your question? Or the code to let us reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_df = pd.read_csv("name.csv", na_values=["NaT"]).dropna(axis=1)
```

Try this, replace the file name with your own.
And if there is a header then add header=0.
I'm assuming that 'NaT' values are string data, so they are not removed.

It is possible to try to delete in ready dataframe if it is rows.

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 'NaT'], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]})


colum = my_df.isin(['NaT']).any()
my_df = my_df.loc[:, ~colum]
```